# Unable to retrieve the Author's information of a file using System.Io in C#

Tags: c#, file, author, system.io.file, system.io.fileinfo

Unable to retrieve Author's information of a file using System.Io in C#.
 I tried with `GetOwner()` method and ii is always gives a static value. 
Kindly help me to get the Author's information under the `File Properties` which are under `Details` Tab.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you show us a piece of code? In this way we can see where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user who created a file, you can try this:

```
string userWhoCreatedTheFile = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(@"your path").GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```